# .NET IEnumerator<string> not advancing on MoveNext when in yield block

Tags: .net, yield-return

The code below (for running in LinqPad) is meant to parse the "foo/skip/bar" string into item objects, skipping over the 'skip' bit, yielding Item objects for "foo" and "bar". When run, 2 "bar" items are produced.

In the TryGetChild method, when "skip" is found, the enumerator is moved from "skip" forward to "bar". However, when execution returns into the calling method, the enumerator is back on "skip".

I think this is some yield block weirdness, as if I do the split in Main() and pass the enumerator into Walk() it works properly. Can someone explain how the enumerator goes back? Is a new one being created?

edit: This is a very simplified version of the seemingly odd situation I have found in my code. I am asking this question out of inquisitiveness rather than looking for a workaround, which I have already found.

```
/* output from program

enumerator moved to foo
enumerator moved to skip
enumerator moved to bar
enumerator moved to bar

Item [] (3 items)  

foo
bar     
bar
*/     


static void Main()
{
    Walk("foo/skip/bar").ToArray().Dump();
}

private static IEnumerable<Item> Walk(string pathString)
{
    var enumerator = pathString.Split('/').ToList().GetEnumerator();
    var current = new Item() { S = "" };
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enumerator moved to " + enumerator.Current);
        yield return current.TryGetChild(enumerator);
    }
}
class Item
{
    public string S { get; set; }

    public Item TryGetChild(IEnumerator<string> enumerator)
    {
        if (enumerator.Current == "skip")
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext(); //iterator moves on to 123
            Console.WriteLine("enumerator moved to " + enumerator.Current);
        }
        return new Item() { S = enumerator.Current };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason your code needs to use this method? It seems like your goals can be achieved in a much simpler manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you see this behaviour is that `List<T>.GetEnumerator()` returns an instance of `List<T>.Enumerator`, which is a **struct**. Thus you are passing a value type to the `TryGetChild()` method, and any mutations on that type (including those done by `MoveNext()`) will *not* be reflected in the caller.

Comment: Damn, I'd just come to that conclusion as well (though not by looking at the IL, just by doing what you suggested in the last sentence. That's quite a good gotcha there...

Comment: @Chris it is and it isn't. It's good to know in general, but relying on passing around an enumerator is asking for trouble regardless.

Comment: Yes, I did consider adding to my comment "and another reason why I'm never going to use an enumerator" directly. It just seems so safe at a glance... :)

Comment: @Chris Yeah, it took me a minute to realize what was happening. "Hmm, the change should be reflected, since he's passing a reference. Wait... is he... Aha!"

Comment: @mcintyre321: no, the var has nothing to do with it. If you make it an explicit type declration you get the exact same behaviour. To get around the bug you would need to pass the iterator as a reference. Basically its to do with how reference and value types are passed. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html is an excellent article which might help to explain this behaviour.

Comment: @Chris I tried with the explicit variable declaration, and it *did* have the desired semantics. Passing around the box is fine, and since it's the *same* box, the mutations are preserved on its contents.

Comment: Ah, actually I've just realised that if you are talking about boxing then you probably cast it to a different type than I did. :) I just explicitly declared it as the type it was rather than as an interface or other.

Comment: It depends if you write IEnumerator<string> enumerator = ... or List<string>.Enumerator enumerator = ... Doesn't help that R# to offers change to var.

Comment: @mcintyre321 R# shouldn't recommend `var` if the type of the initializer expression and the type of variable don't match; it's a semantic change to do otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think `yield` only works when using an `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` loop.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "only works"... Surely it would be working fine if he were not trying to advance the iterator in a separate method...

Comment: `yield` is definitely not the issue. See my answer for what's really going on.